# Explicit matrices of representation of symplectic group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symplectic-group

I would like to obtain explicit matrices for the representations of the Symplectic group $Sp_2(Z)$. For a pair of weights $(a, b)$ I know that the highest weight representations are contained in the tensor product $\otimes^a(M_0) \otimes^b(M_1)$ with two specific representations $M_0$ and $M_1$.

The question is how can I extract the irreducible representation from the tensor product representation? The classical references are mostly glossing over that "detail". Even better is there any software implementation?

Comment: I would look in [Goodman-Wallach](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2522486), e.g. 5.5.21 and the Young symmetrizers in 10.2.8.